# Installation on a Nexus 7 gets stuck while flashing the root filesystem

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Well, a good chunk of my day has been spent on what was supposed to take minutes... here's the rundown

Every time, i get stuck while flashing the root file system (freezing, timing out, or error message)

I seemingly followed all of the steps and troubleshoots, and repeated them, no such luck. i would not count it out that i still messed one of them up, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. It froze and I restarted computer and nexus 7. It's now stuck for a long time on "erasing boot partition".

Comment: There will be **AskUbuntu** users trying to install this.  See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation *Setting up your Nexus 7* **AND** http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntu-installer-for-nexus-7-tablet-made-available-for-devs *"Google’s Nexus 7 tablet is, as Mark Shuttleworth revealed last week, to be Ubuntu’s ‘reference’ device on which the ‘core’ of Ubuntu will be tweaked."*

Comment: What tablet hardware do you have? 8GB or 16GB?

Comment: What steps (and guide) have you followed so far?

Comment: If it's stuck that long then it's probably a bug, probably best to report it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7

Comment: So did anybody who had this issue succeed in installing ubuntu?